# SplitViewController always shows DetailViewController on startup

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a splitViewController setup on Storyboard. Its setup as Master on MasterViewController() and on DetailController on DetailViewController(). Whenever the app launches I always get the DetailViewController on full screen with a navigationBar which I have to pop before the MasterView is presented. I have set self.preferredDisplayMode = .oneBesideSecondary
and I have searched the net for an answer but cannot get. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A few questions for clarification. (I don't use storyboards but am using a `UISplitViewController`. (1) Is your root view controller this split view? (2) What iOS/iPadOS is your target? (3) If the device is an iPad does it work differently? (4) What size class are you speaking about, regular or compact? Apple has really worked on the split view controller the last two annual cycles, and I'm trying to see your issue. Also, you - at least in 14.x - don't "pop" anything. You show/hide. (And a navigation bar is only present in the "Secondary" VC.)

Comment: @dfd Thank you for the reply. As a "base" i have a tabbarcontroller and on the 1st tab I have a splitviewcontroller. target is iOS 14. The secondary VC is always shown first and when I press the back button the primary VC is shown in full screen and not as a .oneBesideSecondary

Comment: Follow up question, based on your comment. Is the split VC is "embedded" inside a tab VC? I think I'm reading you correctly. How does it behave if it *was* the root VC instead? I'm just trying to eliminate something.

Comment: @dfd its not embedded in a VC.. i did not try it as rootVC becuse i use my tabBarVC as root

Comment: I was probably wrong to use the word "embedded". What I was trying to do is see if the behavior of a `UISplitViewController` is different when (a) it's the root VC and/or (b) there a tab bar involved. I only use it - split view - as the root VC and target iOS 14 like you - and only when it's displaying the compact VC do I use a tab bar. Since the VC hierarchy is very different from your's I hoped to eliminate a few things.

Answer (score 0):

from
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656369

> If I embed the split view controller in a container view controller,
> then the problem solved. This is the the most effective solution I
> have ever found.